# Vimeo.php : simple request not working

Tags: php, vimeo-api

I'm trying to use vimeo.php on a WordPress website I'm developing. I have downloaded the library and put it in my theme's folder. I have also created an app on Vimeo API's website. And I use the code below :

```
// Include Vimeo's php library
require_once( "/assets/php/vimeo.php-1.3.0/autoload.php");
$client_id = 'xxxx'; //'Client identifier' in my app
$client_secret = 'xxxx'; // 'Client secrets' in my app
$lib = new \Vimeo\Vimeo($client_id, $client_secret);

function get_Vimeo(){
    $response = $lib->request('https://vimeo.com/6327777', array(), 'GET');
    return $response;
}
```

When I call the get_Vimeo() function I get a `Fatal error: Call to a member function request() on null`.

Vimeo's API is a bit obscure to me, any idea what I did wrong ?

Comment: Check out my answer. Should do the trick. Update me if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofir Baruch's answer was very helpful, but I'm answering my own question for a more thorough fix.
There is indeed a problem with the scope of `$lib`, but there's also an issue with the first request argument. The Vimeo.php library builds an URL like so : 'api.vimeo.com' . 'first_argument'. Here's the fixed code that works for me :

```
// Include Vimeo's php library
require_once( "/assets/php/vimeo.php-1.3.0/autoload.php");
$client_id = 'xxxx'; //'Client identifier' in my app
$client_secret = 'xxxx'; // 'Client secrets' in my app
$lib = new \Vimeo\Vimeo($client_id, $client_secret);

// Set the access token (from my Vimeo API app)
$lib->setToken('xxx...xxx');

function get_Vimeo(){
    global $lib;
    $response = $lib->request('/videos/6327777', array(), 'GET');
    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The term you're looking for is [**Variables Scope**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

> The scope of a variable is the context within which it is defined. For
>   the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope. This single
>   scope spans included and required files as well.

`$lib` is a variable which you've defined in the file.
You can't access it in a function just because it's in the file, it's another scope.

Use `global $lib` in the function in order to access it.

**Example:**

```
$var = 'something';

function testA(){
  echo $var; //null
}

function testB(){
  global $var;
  echo $var; //something
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm so bad at php I didn't even know how global variables worked. I've posted my own answer though because there was another problem preventing my code to work.